# Use a variable in a macro before declaration in C

Tags: c, macros

I found the code below in a project and I'm having problems understanding why GCC doesn't complaint since *dlc* is called before it has been defined.

```
#define CAN_SET_DLC(dlc) (CANCDMOB |= (dlc))


typedef struct
{
    uint8_t mob_n;
    uint8_t handle;
    long id;
    long id_msk;
    uint8_t dlc;
    uint8_t data_pt[8];
    uint8_t status;
} can_msg;
```

¿The variable type of dlc should also be defined?:

```
define CAN_SET_DLC(uint8_t dlc) (CANCDMOB |= (dlc))
```

Comment: It isn't called before dlc gets defined. From this code snipped, it isn't called at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor has no knowledge of variables or any language construct. It is just a token processor.

In `#define a(b) ( b + 1 )` this means that anytime the preprocessor encounters `a(foo)` in the source text, it will replace it with `( foo + 1 )`. Then the compiler will check whether it is correct C.

Comment: token, not string. It is a huge difference

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Re “The preprocessor has no knowledge of… any language construct”: That comes as a surprise to anybody expecting expressions in `#if` statements to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal way to define macro with arguments: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments

Macros just replace text basically so you have to take care about variable type.

Answer (score 1):

No, macros only substitute text (more precisely tokens) and it is done before actual C code compilation. The preprocessor does not know anything about C language.

The preprocessed source code then is compiled by the C compiler.

```
#define CAN_SET_DLC(dlc) ((DLC) |= CANCDMOB)

#define CANCMOB 0x34

int foo(uint8_t z)
{
    CAN_SET_DLC(z);
    return z;
}
```

will result in

```
int foo(uint8_t z)
{
    ((z) |= 0x34);
    return z;
}
```